# asp .net mvc telerik grid and second header column

Tags: model-view-controller, templates, grid, telerik

I use telerik grid with Ajax batch editing for MVC – works just perfect. I have to do the following – group 2 columns under common, additional to the existing header without losing editing capabilities. So technically I need just a way to put additional header line which sill span across 2 columns. I know that I can use just column template but in this way I get a columns but with read only values – code below. I will appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks,
Andy

```
<columns.Template(o => {%>

        <table cellspacing="0" class="data-row">
            <tr>
                <td><%=o.Unit_01%></td>
                <td><%=o.Value_01%></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <%})
    .ClientTemplate("<table cellspacing='0' calss='data-row' <tr><td><#= Unit_01 #></td><td><#= Value_01 #></td></tr></table>")
    .HeaderTemplate(() => {%>
        <table cellspacing="0" class="data-header">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Period 1</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit</td>
                <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <%})
    .Width(200);
```

Comment: Why do you use server and client template for one column at the same time? I suppose you should have solely client template for the batch client editing, if in par with how the Discontinued column here is defined: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingbatch

Comment: The reason why I use two templates is that the initial grid load is done by server site binding after that Ajax comes to play. This is one of possible approach to improve user experience a little bit not wait for Ajax to fill the grid when the page opens first time. This technic is also approved by telerik. It works just like it should. The problem is with a column template which is not editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, got it from telerik support, code below just for the record, has some limitation but in general works for me quite well.

```
 columns.Bound(o => o.Unit_01).Width(49).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style="padding:0", colspan = 2 }) // make the column span
  .HeaderTemplate(() => {
    %>
    <div style="text-align:center" class="t-header t-last">
        <strong>Period 1</strong>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="t-header" style="float:left;width:49px;border-bottom: none">Unit</div> 
        <div class="t-header t-last">Value</div> 
    </div>
    <%
    }
  );
```